# Emoji character () versus simple character, different results for lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding

Tags: string, swift

I have initialized two character constants like this:

```
let emojiCharacter = ""
let simpleCharacter = "a"
```

I am printing result for lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding like this:

```
println("\(emojiCharacter) countElements returns \(countElements(emojiCharacter))")
println("\(simpleCharacter) countElements returns \(countElements(simpleCharacter))")
println("\(emojiCharacter) UTF16StringEncoding lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding returns \(emojiCharacter.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF16StringEncoding))")
println("\(simpleCharacter) UTF16StringEncoding lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding returns \(simpleCharacter.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF16StringEncoding))")
println("\(emojiCharacter) NSUTF8StringEncoding lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding returns \(emojiCharacter.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))")
println("\(simpleCharacter) NSUTF8StringEncoding lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding returns \(simpleCharacter.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))")
```

Below are the results:

```
 countElements returns 1
a countElements returns 1
 UTF16StringEncoding lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding returns 4
a UTF16StringEncoding lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding returns 2
 NSUTF8StringEncoding lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding returns 4
a NSUTF8StringEncoding lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding returns 1
```

I am confused by the results because according to my understanding if we are using UTF16StringEncoding then it treats each character as 2 bytes or 16 bits and if we use UTF8StringEncoding then it treats each character as 1 byte or 8 bits, so when I tried to log lengthOfBytes for simpleCharacter using UTF16StringEncoding it displayed 2 bytes and for NSUTF8StringEncoding it displayed 1 byte.

I understand that emoji characters are represented differently but then why it is always returning result as 4?

Also if I want to iterate over each character in string I will always use countElements, but then exactly when will it be helpful to use lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding?

Please suggest.

Comment: UTF encodings are magical in the sense that as more characters are defined, we can add bytes to the size of each individual character, which means we don't need to create new encodings for different character sets (such as ASCII or ALT codes). This video provides a nice explanation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MijmeoH9LT4

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The size of the UTF encoding simply defines the **minimum** number of bytes to be used to represent a character. However, certain characters, like the emoji you are using, require more than 2 bytes to be represented. All characters take at least the minimum defined in the encoding, and up to as many bytes as is necessary.

There are various reasons that the different encodings exists, but to give you a quick example: If you know all characters you are going to use are 2 bytes or less, you can use a UTF-16 encoded string so that you can immediately jump to a character at any index like a normal array because they are stored uniformly in memory. If you instead encoded it as UTF-8, you would no longer be able to jump in the array safely because some characters would be represented in 1 byte and others would be represented in more than 1 byte making the position of a specific index in memory unclear.

Comment: This answer properly describes Unicode. Unfortunately many programmers do not fully understand how string encoding works, [this is a great must-read](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Answer (score 1):

Emoji are always longer than the types you specified (UTF16 and UTF8) because both of those sizes are already full, so can't store the additional symbols needed by the Emoji pack.

As you have already figured out, the basic Latin alphabet can fit into a single byte: http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf  (Note that when reading the table, the U+XXXX value is a 16-bit hex code, so U+0061 = (binary)0000 0000 0110 0001, which is the lower case a)

As you add more languages and symbols, you start needing to use two bytes: http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf (U+00E4 = 1100 0011 1010 0100 = ä)

However, I need to clairify a point here because I was confused on it. As  explained by Drewag in his answer and  John Estropia in my answer's comments, the byte size of Unicode only describes the minimum size of a charcter in that encoding. As you saw, you can have a larger Emoji character in UTF8 encoding, it just takes more space.

There is no 3 byte minimum encoding because it wouldn't make sense with the most common CPUs in use today. The latest standard of Unicode is 32-bits (4 bytes) and is where Emoji starts to fit in: http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/Unicode-6.1/U61-1F600.pdf . Notice that there are now five hex values following the U+, rather than the four we have seen before, which requires at least 3 bytes of addressing.

So, if you were to use UTF32, you would see the Basic Latin characters appearing at the same size at the Emoji.

As an example of when you would want to programmatically find the lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding, imagine you're writing a program which compresses, through some algorithm*, a text file. In order to encode or decode, you will need to know the length of a character in the original file. You are somehow given the encoding, which can be different for different text files. You could either have a mess of if/else blocks, containing every possible encoding (at the time you're writing the program), or you could have a nice variable which gets its value from lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding (insert encoding here).
*I'm thinking Huffman compression, but there are probably other examples...

I wish I could think of a better - everyday - example! But, in general, I would say that it's not often you would need to know the byte length of a character in a given encoding.

Comment: It is misleading to say that "3 bytes were skipped because computers work in powers of two". UTF-8 and UTF-16 encoding allows 3-byte characters, as well as 4-byte ones. Avoiding this confusion is precisely the reason why Apple chose to ommit a `length()` method on Swift strings.

Comment: As we have already demonstrated, 3-byte unicode are stored in 4-bytes, in the same way as you can store UTF8 characters in a UTF16 slot. 3-byte Unicode characters were skipped because it would make no sense to have a 24-bit character when, except for old, mostly unsupported 16-bit systems and very strange (probably also unsupported) 24-bit cpus, all processors already have 32-bit or wider pipelines and are only accepting values in increments of 2^x. There's also probably trouble when you try to write 24-bit characters to disk, since they would rarely end on block boundaries.

Comment: @John I guess I should put that another way. To discuss the intricacies of CPUs, hardware-level and compiler-level optimizations, CISC vs. RISC, and data storage would be wildly off-topic for this answer. Whole university courses can be made to discuss this material. To gloss over the reasoning for not having 24-bit data with a correct but incomplete reason seems to be a much better fit. If you would like to make an edit to more completely explain why there is no UTF24, you have my blessing.

Comment: I apologize if I sounded that way, but I didn't mean to say you were flat-out wrong, just that it may be misleading. I've debugged a lot of string encoding/decoding problems because some people think UTF8=1 and UTF16=2, and I think it's because they misunderstood the possibility of 3 and more bytes per character. One thing I'd clarify though, UTF-8 does allow storage of 3-byte unicode characters (e.g. Chinese characters).

Comment: @John Oh. I would have been one of the people causing the problem you would be debugging for... I see now what you're saying. Thank you. I'll make some edits. Sorry I sounded like such a hothead!